# Fan Control AMD HD4890 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, fan

The GPU fan for my computer is always running fast.

I've tried several things such as using scripts like `fancontrol`, but it didn't work to fix the issue.

I saw that AMD does not provide the proprietary drivers or Catalyst control center for the older GPU in my computer.

Do I need to downgrade to an older release of Ubuntu in order to make the fan speed working correctly, or to get the AMD drivers to control the fan?

Comment: Getting the drivers should be better!

Comment: The problem is that there aren`t drivers anymore for that gpu on ubunto 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try for stop fan

```
sudo echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/cur_state
```

or

```
sudo echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/cur_state
```

for start fan

Comment: This is s temporary solution!

Comment: Both commands are not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Radeon HD 6870 on latest Ubuntu 18. AMD driver for this card aren't supported. So I tried:

1. Changing power method `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method`
2. Instaling latest opensoure driver from `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
3. Lm-sensor with fan control.

Nothing works. Fan still works with full speed.

**EDIT: I've solved it**

I used these two utilities to download the bios from the video card, edit it and flash it back to the card. Utilites are for windows, but after bios flash fan works quietly everywhere.

- Radeon BIOS editor (RBE) https://www.techpowerup.com/rbe/
- ATI Winflash https://www.techpowerup.com/download/ati-winflash/

Firstly check if RBE supports your card. Than you can do it.

1. Download bios from your card using ATI Winflash - button Save.
2. Open bios file in RBE - button Load Bios.
3. Go to Fan setting and click to button Set all fan settings to recommended values
4. Save bios to file - button Save Bios.
5. Open edited bios file in ATI Winflash - button Load image.
6. Program to video card - button Program.
7. Reboot.

Immediately after reboot fan works quietly. So open source driver can be used. **Thanks RBE!**